# Working with hover background Change on a DIV

Tags: css, background, opacity

I've been  trying to achieve the effect of mouse over on a picture which dims its background and brings over a text on top.

Then I wanted a nice centralized text when I moused over.

These both things were achieved, but then I ran into two small problems.

- How can I not dim the text on top when I dim the background of the picture
- How can I centralized the text without specifying width and height of the picture (to enable responsive design)

### HTML

```
<div id="bottomWide">            
    <ul>
       <li class="first">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt=""> 
            <div class="all-canvas">
                <div class="all-text">
                    <span class="title">A Heading</span><br>
                    <span class="text">Couples of Lines of Text will come here</span><br>
                    <span class="shop">See Details.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="second">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="">
                 <div class="all-canvas">
                <div class="all-text">
                    Some text here, style as needed
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul> 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#bottomWide{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;


}

#bottomWide ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#bottomWide li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    text-align:justify;
    float: left;


     /* For Mouse Over*/
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#bottomWide li:last-child img { 
   border-left: 4px solid #fff;
}
#bottomWide img{
    width:100%;
}



#bottomWide li div.all-canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* 100% will equal the dimensions of the image, as nothing else will be inside the .container */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    /* This will create the fade effect */
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    /* Include all required vendor prefixes for opacity and transition */

    margin: 0 auto;
}
#bottomWide li:last-child div.all-canvas {
    margin-left: 4px;
}



#bottomWide li div.all-canvas:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#bottomWide li:last-child div.all-canvas:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

div.all-text {
    height:358px; /* This is what I want to change to %*/
    width: 623px; /* This is what I want to change to %*/ 
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid silver;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

div.all-text span.title { padding: 3px; font: 18px/1.35 "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

The Output looks something like this:-

[image]
(Notice the dim text on top of the picture; hoping to make it solid)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set opacity to an element, all children (including the text) will have the opacity as well. You could try changing the background color using rgba:

```
#bottomWide li div.all-canvas:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}
```

You'll still need to toggle opacity 0 to 1 so it can become visible, but the background-color should be transparent.

Centering the text will be a lot more tricky because you're trying to make it responsive. Since the text won't have a fixed height, you will probably have to use Javascript to calculate it. You could start with this CSS:

```
.theText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px; // Should be half of the element height
}
```

You'll have to use javascript to measure the height of .theText and set a negative margin-top accordingly...

Comment: Thanks. This works. Any idea How I can centralized the text without specifying width and height of the picture (to enable responsive design)